# Подобрать html тег

Tags: html, html5

Здравствуйте. Хочу добавить дерево на сайт и столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. Есть, приблизительно, такая верстка:

```
<ul>
  <li> <smttag>Тут может быть ваш html</smttag>
    <ul>
      <li> <smttag>И тут тоже произвольный html</smttag> </li> // типа подменю
      ...
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <smttag>Похоже на предыдущее</smttag> </li>
  <li> <smttag>И еще</smttag>
    <ul>
      <li>....</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Дело в том, что надо будет динамически изменять стили для всего содержимого li, кроме тега ul (подсветить найденное без наследников, к примеру). Пришел к тому, что надо содержимое во что-нибудь обернуть. Вопрос в том, во что, с точки зрения семантики верстки, оборачивать? Или пользоваться div-ами и не выдумывать?

Comment: семантика это же не про структуру в общем-то, а про смысл в большей мере. тут самое место для класса. (не все новые html5 тэги - семантические)

Comment: @eicto Класс то само собой разумеется. Вот [ссылка][1]. Я хотел подсветить только li с текстом "It's a test. /job/poli/" (класс hl), а подсвечивается и дочерний ul, который светить не надо. Поэтому я подумал, что будет правильно содержимое каждого li упрятать в какой-то тег, а ul ставить рядом. Так я вот спрашиваю - во что лучше паковать? Кроме div-а ничего не напрашивается.

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/s3G88/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

используйте div, span

Comment: @soledar10 Подтвердили мою догадку, что на этот счет нету никакого "специализированого" тега